# get google merchant tags from rss?

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to parse this feed: http://fireflowergames.com/?feed=products&sale=1

The tags I am interested in are the google merchant tags like `<g:price>` for example.

I am using http://lastrss.oslab.net/ to grab the RSS but unsure how to get it to grab stuff like the price out of that RSS?

Here's my code so far:

```
require_once('lastRSS.php');

$rss = new lastRSS;

$rss->cache_dir = ''; 

$rssurl = 'http://fireflowergames.com/?feed=products&sale=1'; 

if ($rs = $rss->get($rssurl)) 
{
    foreach ($rs['items'] as $item)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($item);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo $item['title'] . '<br />';
    }
}
else 
{
    die ('Error: RSS file not found...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer myself, using lastRSS if you are parsing an rss feed with custom tags in it, you need to add those tags to `var $itemtags = array(` in the lastRSS.php file.